# Code Coverage - How can an if be partially touched when the statement in the if runs

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have the following code 
[image]

My question is how can the `if` condition be partially covered when the true part of the if condition runs?  It is a short circuit And `&&` but both sides must be evaluated for the true condition to fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't tested the conditions that would cause it to be false i.e. not executed

e.g. when

```
(productBuildType.MasterId.HasValue) == false
```

or

```
(productBuildType.MasterId.Value > 0) == false
```

to test those I would have one test case where

```
productBuildType.MasterId = null
```

and another where

```
productBuildType.MasterId = 0
```

Comment: Interesting, I was going to blast Visual studio for not knowing there was not an else clause, but I guess it does make sense since you have to see how the program is run when the if is not execute, thus making the If condition mandatory